# Java - как получить информацию из HTML-страницы

Tags: java, html, jsoup, парсер

Пишу приложение на Java, связанное с парсингом исходного кода страницы. Вопрос заключается в следующем. Пытаюсь парсить исходный код следующим образом:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
```

Парсится нормально. Но(!) смотрю полученый исходный код - там не все блоки. К примеру, в браузере с помощью "Исследовать элемент" я этот блок и всё, что в нем есть вижу, а в полученом исходном коде с помощью Jsoup этого блока нет. Собственно, вопрос: как парсить весь исходный код целиком?

Comment: Его нет, потому что видимо он размещается при помощи Java-Script, возможен такой вариант?

Comment: Да, он, скорее всего сгенирирован при помощи JavaScript. Есть ли возможно спарсить такие блоки кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятнее всего *желаемый элемент создается при помощи JavaScript кода* запускаемым браузером и/или с помощью дополнительных API запросов. *JSoup - это не браузер* и в нем нет JavaScript движка. В `doc` Вы получаете исходный "статический" HTML.

Вариантов решить эту проблему несколько:

- автоматизировать настоящий браузер через [`selenium`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp), открыть желаемую страницу в selenium-powered браузере, дать ему выполнить свою работу по загрузке страницы и пропарсить нужные данные; далее либо получить исходный код страницы через `getPageSource()` и отдать это `JSoup` на парсинг, либо продолжить спользовать selenium webdriver API
- инспектировать, как загружается и формируется страница (с помощью browser developer tools), если браузер делает дополнительные реквесты, повторить их в своем Java коде

Также иногда бывает, что нужные данные уже присутствуют в HTML, но только в другом месте. Например, иногда в `script` тегах - тоже проверьте это.